# Naming convention for async functions with async delegates

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, naming-conventions, naming

I am developing an API and I am looking for a good, understandable naming convention.

Consider these different type of overloads of the same functionality:

```
public async Task<TResult> DoAsync<T,TResult>(Func<T,TResult> func)
{
   var t = await ProcessAsync();
   return func(t);
}

public async Task<TResult> DoAsyncAlsoAwaitDelegateAsync<T,TResult>(Func<T,Task<TResult>> funcAsync);
{
   var t = await ProcessAsync();
   return await funcAsync(t);
}
```

Note that I cannot make an overload `DoAsync<T,TResult>(Func<T,Task<TResult>> func)` because it would result in ambiguous calls.

Users could solve the ambiguous call by specifying the parameter name when calling, but I would rather not create unnecessary confusion if possible.

`DoAlsoAwaitDelegateAsync` is a pretty clumsy name, so I'm looking for alternative naming conventions here.

Comment: I think you’d be better off asking this question in the code review SE site

Comment: @Adelin I think OP is looking for a naming convention, something which should be found elsewhere. This is too stubby to review.

Comment: @Adelin Good point. I attempted to flag this question so that it can be moved but the codereview site is not among the alternative site options.

Comment: The question in it's current scope would be **off-topic** for code review @DavidS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If** you have to accept a delegate at all (rather than just returning the computed value to the caller and letting them do their own function/task composition) I would just have the version that accepts a `Func<T,Task<TResult>>`.

Leave it up to the caller whether they have their own asynchronous function or just give you a function that executes entirely synchronously and then returns [`Task.FromResult()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922(v=vs.110).aspx). Rather than (currently) writing two versions of your function that just differs in whether *it* knows that the delegate *may* exploit some asynchrony.

Comment: Isn't that a performance hit to always wrap it in a completed task? I am not concerned about a single call of course, but if this was iterated many times.

Comment: Unless or until there is a proven performance *issue* - I.e. we have performance goals and have measured that the current code doesn't meet those goals I favour simplicity. I wouldn't *expect* there to be a measurable overhead here.